# Customize Salesforce customer communities

Tags: chatter, community

Below is the screenshot of salesforce customer communities from one of  videos of salesforce ( http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/features/communities.jsp ).Can someone help me in customizing the look and feel of chatter part.How to built the entire chatter functionality like the one shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, some of the marketing material put out around products like Communities and Site.com can be very liberal on what is "possible" on a public facing site. In this scenario, I believe you would need to custom code the entire Chatter feed to get that exact look and feel. You can achieve that using custom CSS/Javascript and the [ConnectApi](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_overview.htm). I have done some work in the past ([Chatter Image Gallery](http://jessealtman.com/2014/03/chatter-image-gallery-using-connectapi/) & [Extended](http://jessealtman.com/2014/03/extending-chatter-image-gallery-using-connectapi/)) with the [ConnectApi Namespace](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) and it isn't too bad to use if you want to go that route.

However, with that said, you can probably avoid all of that and just use the correct [Visualforce Chatter](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter11/Chatter+Components+for+Visualforce) tag. The only real difference between the standard Chatter feed and what you have in your screenshot above is the button. The Chatter button says *Share*, not *Ask*. In this scenario, I would use the [`<chatter:feed>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_compref_chatter_feed.htm|SkinName=webhelp) tag:

> Displays the Chatter EntityFeed for a record or an UserProfileFeed for
>   a user. Note that Chatter components are unavailable for Visualforce
>   pages on Force.com sites. Ext JS versions less than 3 should not be
>   included on pages that use this component.

**Note:** In the past, I have seen Salesforce Communities used in conjunction with Force.com Sites to provide a public facing and authenticated facing site. In this scenario, this tag will not work on a Force.com Sites page.

For adding the other functionality (*Message My Advisor* for instance), look into [Publisher Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm&language=en_US).

> The publisher actions feature lets you create actions and add them to
>   the Chatter publisher on the home page, on the Chatter tab, in Chatter
>   groups, and on record detail pages. You can also customize the order
>   in which the standard Chatter actions appear, including Post, File,
>   Link, and Poll.
>
> Actions let users do more in Chatter, like create records and log
>   calls directly in the feed. There are four general types of actions:
>   create actions, log-a-call actions, update actions, and custom
>   actions.
>
> - *Create actions* let users create records. They’re different from the Quick Create and Create New features on the home page, because
>     create actions respect validation rules and field requiredness, and
>     you can choose each action’s fields.
> - *Log a call* actions let users record the details of phone calls or other customer interactions. These call logs are saved as completed
>     tasks.
> - *Update actions* let users make changes to a record from the record’s feed.
> - *Custom actions* are Visualforce pages or canvas apps with functionality you define. For example, you might create a custom
>     action to let users write comments longer than 5000 characters, or one
>     that integrates a video conferencing application so support agents can
>     communicate visually with customers.
>
> For create, log-a-call, and custom actions, you can create either
>   object-specific actions or global actions. Update actions must be
>   object-specific.

**Note:** You may find the [Publisher Actions Implementation Guide](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/actions_impl_guide.pdf) useful.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse Altman. Is it possible to mimic left panel of chatter (chatter views) like "ME","BookMarked","People","Group","Files","Topics" using standard visualforce chatter components

Comment: I don't believe so @sf.dev.